# Apache shiro remember me not working

Tags: shiro, remember-me

Im trying to use the rememberme feature from apache shiro, but its not working.

I have this shiro.ini

```
[main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory   
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource  
ds.resourceName = java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS


# JDBC realm config  
jdbcRealm = br.com.myproject.web.service.security.JdbcRealmImpl
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND status = 1
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/** = authcBasic
```

This is my JdbcRealmImpl:

```
public class JdbcRealmImpl extends JdbcRealm {

    public JdbcRealmImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(
            final AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

        final AuthenticationInfo info = super.doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);

        final UserDB userDB = new UserDB();
        final User user = userDB.getUserByUsername((String) token.getPrincipal());

        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, info.getCredentials(), getName());
    }    

}
```

Since this is a web service project i have a login service:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
public Response login(@FormParam("username") final String username, @FormParam("password") final String password, @FormParam("remember") final boolean remember) {

    final Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        final UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
        try {
            token.setRememberMe(remember);
            currentUser.login(token);
        } catch (final AuthenticationException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Invalid user").build();
        }
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

The problem is that SecurityUtils.getSubject().isRemembered() always return false even when i set token.setRememberMe(true);

Is there any configuration that im missing?

Answer (score 2):

Subject.isRemembered() is a little tricky in Shiro.  It only returns true if the Subject has a valid Remember Me setting (cookie, etc) AND the Subject is not Authenticated.  Details here: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#isRemembered()

So, I suspect that your Remember Me is working fine, but your expectations for Subject.isRemembered() doesn't match what the method actually does.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you logout from your application throught shiro logout remember me will be erased. To try make session time out just one minute let session expire itself and reload main page now you will find that user is actually being remembered. LOGOUT CLEARS REMEMBER ME.

If you want to use remember me still after logout you can try to extend securitymanager and use this securitymanger for your application.

```
public class CustomSecurityManager extends DefaultWebSecurityManager {
    @Override
    protected void beforeLogout(Subject subject)
    {
        super.removeRequestIdentity(subject);
    }    
}
```